# VBA Multiply elements of subset of array

Tags: arrays, vba

I have an array containing 5 integers. For example:

```
myArray = Array(3, 5, 2, 9, 3)
```

I want to write a loop that loops through the elements of the array, and on each iteration returns the product of the current element and all elements to the *right* of it.

In the example above:

```
3 * 5 * 2 * 9 * 3
    5 * 2 * 9 * 3
        2 * 9 * 3
            9 * 3
                3
```

My non-VBA thinking was along the lines of:

```
for i in myArray
    product(myArray[i:])
```

But I don't know how to write this in VBA, especially since it doesn't support array subsetting. Any help is welcome.

Comment: If the order of the products is not important then you can loop backwards over the array and output the running product on each iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two loops:

```
Sub foo()
Dim myArray
myArray = Array(3, 5, 2, 9, 3)
Dim i&, j&
Dim output As Double

For i = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
    output = 1
    For j = i To UBound(myArray)
        output = output * myArray(j)
    Next j
    Debug.Print output
Next i
End Sub
```

---

[image]